# How to disable an input on a certain state in the view. Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a directive that I am using in two different places in my app, and I need to disable an input in the directive's template in one state in my app, but not the other.

I've tried:

```
<input type="number" ng-model="data" ng-disabled='$state.current.name == "findRates"'/>
```

With no luck. If I change the ng-disable to read as follows:

```
ng-disabled='checkState()'
```

With the checkState function in the controller:

```
$scope.checkState = function() {
  if ($state.current.name == 'findRates') {
    return true;
  }
};
```

This works just fine, however, I'd like to do this in just the view, without needing the extra bit in the controller. Am I just missing something? I've tried using $location as well, with no luck, and I'd rather use $state but I'm open to any suggestions.Thank you in advance.

Comment: $state is not available in view

Comment: because your controller gets the `$state` dependency, view gets exposure to only `$scope` variables, so put variable on it something like `$scope.shouldShow = $state.current.name == 'findRates'` and then use `shouldShow` on view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your controller gets the `$state` as dependency, But view gets exposure to only `$scope` variables, so put variable on it something like

`$scope.shouldDisable = $state.current.name == 'findRates'`

and then use `shouldDisable` on view

```
<input type="number" ng-model="data" ng-disabled="shouldDisable"/>
```

Comment: You should prefer the `is` method that comes with ui router. `$state.is('findRates'); // returns true/false`

Comment: For one, it's less typing! Secondly, it's a safer way to do this comparison.  Thirdly, you can also compare relative state names this way as well. `$state.is('.item')` would be true if your absolute state was `user.cart.item`.

Comment: its not really "less" typing.. its just syntactical sugar and agree with second point but OP used the first way so I suggested answer with same approach.